# The calculation of an Dual norm

Tags: analytic-geometry

I computing dual norm $ \|v\|_\ast = \sup_{\|x\|\leq1} \langle v, x\rangle $.

For example, I process like this:
$x_1 = (2, 1); x_2 = (5, 10); x_3 = (8, 10)$. As norm of $x$ must be $\|x\| \leq 1$, I normalized vectors and I get this : $ x_1 = (2/\sqrt{5}, 1/\sqrt{5}); x_2 = (5/\sqrt{125}, 10/\sqrt{125}); x_3 = (8/\sqrt{164}, 10/\sqrt{164}) $.

How to choose $v$ to do the calculation? 
The norm of $v$ must it also be lower or equal to $1$? 
After calculation, I don't think I will have an interval to be able to find the supremum, hence my question of how to find the supremum?
In other manuals, I also see $\|v\|_\ast = \max_{\|x\|\leq1} \langle v, x\rangle $. Which the good formula?

Comment: You don't choose $v$, it's given -- you're calculating $\|v\|_*$ so you must know it in advance.  Then you consider all $x$ such that $\|x\|\leq 1$ and find those values of $x$ that lead to the supremum.  I'm afraid I have no idea what $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ are supposed to be, and you really need to state what space (${\mathbb R}^2$?) you're working in as well.

Comment: The $x$ are points I got and I work into $\mathbb{R}^2$. I normalize because the formula say $\|x\| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using the usual inner product on ${\mathbb R}^2$ and that your $\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2}$ and $\mathbf{x_3}$ are all vectors that $v$ takes on in order for the question "find $\|v\|_*$" to make sense.

So, by definition of the dual norm, we have
$$\|v\|_* = \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |v(x)| = \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |\langle v,x\rangle| $$
where the definition of the inner product is
$$\langle v,x\rangle = v_1\cdot x_1 + v_2\cdot x_2 $$

$x_1$ and $x_2$ here *without* boldface are the components of $x$.  Taking $v=\mathbf{x_1}$ we have that $(v_1, v_2) = (2,1)$ and so we need to find
$$ \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |2\cdot x_1 + 1\cdot x_2| $$
By inspection we see that this is maximised when $x_1 =1$ and $x_2=0$ (note that $\|x\| = \sqrt{(x_1^2+x_2^2 )} = \sqrt{1^2+0^2}=1$) and so we obtain
$$ \|v\|_* = 2 $$
You should be able to do the other two vector now by substituting in $v=\mathbf{x_2}$ and $v=\mathbf{x_3}$ and identifying the maximum.